# Unity GroundCheck always returning false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm following brackey's fps movement tutorial. I've copied all the code correctly.

But the `isGrounded` value is always false, even if the player is touching the ground.

[image]

The Ground is also on the layer "Ground"

and here's my code

```
// non related variables
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 12f;
//the gravity
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
//the transform groundcheck, it's attached to the groundcheck object
    public Transform groundCheck;

    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
// layer mask groundmask. 
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {   
        // check if the groundcheck transform is colliding with the ground, which always for //some reason returns false.

        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);
// make the set y velocity to 0. when groundcheck touches the ground
        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = 0;
        }
        
// the movement code (not related)
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
// move the player acording the gravity.
        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Comment: Is your ground on the correct layer? Where is the groundcheck object placed? Is the distance enough to reach it?

Comment: @derHugo yes. the ground is on the Ground layer. the groundcheck object object is placed near the bottom of the player as shown in the image i attached to the question. and yes, the distance is enough.

Comment: The ground check itself shouldn't have a collider itself .. not even any component at all ;) doe the ground have a collider?

Comment: Yes. the ground has a collider

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using CharacterController, you can use a build-in function

```
    void Update()
    {     
        if (controller.isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = 0;
        }
        //the rest of your code
    }
```

[CharacterController docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html)

Comment: I've tried the following and it does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Two things.

First, you don't need to pass in that layer mask. Layer masks are only for when you are trying to ignore another object not detect it. So get rid of that ground mask in CheckSphere.

Second, make sure your ground has a collider and is set on. Unity physics engine looks for colliders and if it doesn't see one it won't register anything.

Comment: And what of you only want to make the ground check against the ground and not other colliders like e.g. your player collider itself ....?

Comment: I've tried what you said but still doesn't work. sorry.